# ruby on the rails rake aborted invalid_date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to run the Rails app 'Simpsons by the Data' (source: https://github.com/toddwschneider/flim-springfield) however whenever I try to run the command `bundle exec rake import_data`

the following error is returned:

```
Called from /Users/XXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/activesupport-4.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'load_dependency'
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: invalid date
/Users/XXXX/flim-springfield/app/models/episode.rb:52:in 'parse'
```

I have PostgreSQL 11.1 on MacOS X installed and I have changed the date style from ISO, MDY to ISO DMY as I stupidly thought this would help but it didn't work.

This is my Gem file:

```
 *** LOCAL GEMS *** 

bigdecimal (default: 1.3.0)
bundler (2.0.1, default: 1.17.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
did_you_mean (1.1.0)
executable-hooks (1.6.0)
gem-wrappers (1.4.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
json (default: 2.0.2)
minitest (5.10.1)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
openssl (default: 2.0.2)
pg (1.1.4)
power_assert (0.4.1)
psych (default: 2.2.2)
rake (12.3.2, 12.3.1, 12.0.0)
rdoc (default: 5.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (3.2.3)
xmlrpc (0.2.1)
```

Has anyone else run into a problem like this while using this Rails app or could even point me in the right direction? I am completely new to this and as this is the first Rails app that I have ever run, I am not sure how to progress. :(

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: did the rake db:migrate worked for you?

Comment: What is on line 52 of `app/models/episode.rb`? Presumably something like `Time.parse(...)` ... But what value is it trying to parse? Something in your database? What value?

Comment: @Javier Mendéndez Rico, yes rake db:migrate worked fine - I just ran into problems at this stage :(

Comment: @Tom Lord the code is trying to parse a string to a Date object value: ep.original_air_date = if cells[6].inner_text == "LABF11"
              "2009-03-22".to_date
            else
              Date.parse(cells[5].inner_text)

Comment: Also sorry if that is difficult to read - I’m answering on mobile rn

Comment: Ok, and what is the value of `cells[5].inner_text`? This information is absolutely crucial to the question, as we need to know how to reproduce the problem.